# Действие на потерю фокуса в `EditText`

Tags: android, android-edittext

У меня есть несколько `EditText`,и мне нужно проверять на валидность когда фокус теряется.

Вот сам код:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

String[] countries;
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
String[] data;
public static EditText etBookingName;
public static EditText etBookingLastname;
public static EditText etBookingBirthday;
public static AutoCompleteTextView etBookingNationality;
public static Spinner spinner;
public static EditText etBookingPassport;
public static EditText etExpiryDate;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.booking_list_items, null);
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingNationality);
        etBookingName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingName);
        etBookingLastname = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingLastname);
        etBookingBirthday = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingBirthday);
        etBookingPassport = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingPassport);
        rgBookingGender = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rgBookingGender);
        etExpiryDate = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etDocumentExpiryDate);

        etBookingNationality.setAdapter(nationAdapter);
        etBookingBirthday.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("##.##.####", etBookingBirthday));
        etExpiryDate.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("##.##.####", etExpiryDate));


            }
        });

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        etBookingName.setOnFocusChangeListener(validate);
        etBookingLastname.setOnFocusChangeListener(validate);
        etBookingBirthday.setOnFocusChangeListener(validate);
        etBookingPassport.setOnFocusChangeListener(validate);
        etExpiryDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(validate);
        etBookingNationality.setOnFocusChangeListener(validate);
    }

    return convertView;
}



    View.OnFocusChangeListener validate = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        if(v == etBookingName && !hasFocus) {
            validation_name(etBookingName);
        }
        else if(v == etBookingLastname && !hasFocus) {
            validation_last_name(etBookingLastname);
        }
        else if (v == etBookingBirthday && !hasFocus) {
            validation_birthday(etBookingBirthday);
        }
        else if (v == etBookingPassport && !hasFocus) {
            validation_passport(etBookingPassport);
        }
        else if (v == etExpiryDate && !hasFocus) {
            validation_expiry(etExpiryDate);
        }
        else if(v == etBookingNationality && !hasFocus) {
            validation_nation(etBookingNationality);
        }
    }
};
```

А Валидации типа этого:

```
static void validation_name(EditText edit) throws NumberFormatException {
    String name = edit.getText().toString();
    if (name.length() == 0) {
        edit.setError("Введите имя");
    } else if (!name.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
        edit.setError("Введите имя латинскими буквами");
    }
}
static void validation_last_name(EditText edit) throws NumberFormatException {
    String lastName = edit.getText().toString();
    if (lastName.length() == 0) ........
```

Не работает, точнее валидация срабатывает когда просто кликаешь на EditText, а мне нужно чтобы валидация срабатывала когда фокус теряется!

**Вопрос:** Что я пропустил?

Comment: hasFocus это что? Почему не помогло?

Comment: Обновил вопрос! Не помогло - никаких результатов!

Comment: А что значит "просто наводишь"?

Comment: Неправильно выразился, удалю!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPD_1** (дабы не засорять ответ лишней информацией удалил все не относящееся к решению проблемы)

После некоторых экспериментов выяснилось, что при клике на `EditText` находящийся внутри группы в `ExpandableListView` фокус скачет несколько раз подряд, то появляется, то пропадает. Внутри других компонентов такого поведения замечено не было.

У меня не получилось решить эту проблему стандартными средствами андроид, поэтому я написал небольшой костыль, работающий как часы и решающий данную проблему.

На словах решение выглядит так:

1. Проинициализировать все части компонента в конструкторе адаптера, в переопределенных методах из `BaseExpandableListAdapter` (таких как `getGroupView`, `getChildView` и т.п.) возвращать проинициализированные ранее части компонента
2. При изменении фокуса на 200 миллисекунд отписываться от события смены фокуса, потом опять подписываться

Вот полностью работоспособный пример с двумя группами:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
        ArrayList<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        groups.add("Group 1");
        groups.add("Group 2");
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, groups);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;

    private ArrayList<ViewGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<EditText> nameEditTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<EditText> lastNameEditTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<EditText> birthdayEditTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<EditText> passportEditTexts = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> groups) {
        mContext = context;
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {
            initGroup(groups.get(i));
        }
        addOnFocusChangeListeners(onFocusChangeListener);
    }

    private void initGroup(String groupTitle) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
        TextView textGroup = (TextView) group.findViewById(R.id.textGroup);
        textGroup.setText(groupTitle);
        groups.add(group);
        initGroupContent();
    }

    private void initGroupContent() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View groupContent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        views.add(groupContent);

        nameEditTexts.add((EditText) groupContent.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText));
        lastNameEditTexts.add((EditText) groupContent.findViewById(R.id.lastNameEditText));
        birthdayEditTexts.add((EditText) groupContent.findViewById(R.id.birthdayEditText));
        passportEditTexts.add((EditText) groupContent.findViewById(R.id.passportEditText));
    }

    private void addOnFocusChangeListeners(View.OnFocusChangeListener listener) {
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {
            nameEditTexts.get(i).setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
            lastNameEditTexts.get(i).setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
            birthdayEditTexts.get(i).setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
            passportEditTexts.get(i).setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
        }
    }

    View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                addOnFocusChangeListeners(null);
                startTimer();
                return;
            }
            EditText edit = (EditText) v;
            if (hasEditText(nameEditTexts, v)) validateName(edit);
            else if (hasEditText(lastNameEditTexts, v)) validateLastName(edit);
            else if (hasEditText(birthdayEditTexts, v)) validateBirthday(edit);
            else if (hasEditText(passportEditTexts, v)) validatePassport(edit);
        }
    };

    private boolean hasEditText(ArrayList<EditText> list, View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) == v) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                addOnFocusChangeListeners(onFocusChangeListener);
            }
        }, 200);
    }

    static void validateName(EditText edit) {
        String text = edit.getText().toString();
        if (text.length() == 0) edit.setError("Name error text");
        else edit.setError(null);
    }

    static void validateLastName(EditText edit) {
        String text = edit.getText().toString();
        if (text.length() == 0) edit.setError("LastName error text");
        else edit.setError(null);
    }

    static void validateBirthday(EditText edit) {
        String text = edit.getText().toString();
        if (text.length() == 0) edit.setError("Birthday error text");
        else edit.setError(null);
    }

    static void validatePassport(EditText edit) {
        String text = edit.getText().toString();
        if (text.length() == 0) edit.setError("Passport error text");
        else edit.setError(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        nameEditTexts.get(groupPosition).setError(null);
        lastNameEditTexts.get(groupPosition).setError(null);
        birthdayEditTexts.get(groupPosition).setError(null);
        passportEditTexts.get(groupPosition).setError(null);
        nameEditTexts.get(groupPosition).setText("");
        lastNameEditTexts.get(groupPosition).setText("");
        birthdayEditTexts.get(groupPosition).setText("");
        passportEditTexts.get(groupPosition).setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        nameEditTexts.get(groupPosition).setError(null);
        lastNameEditTexts.get(groupPosition).setError(null);
        birthdayEditTexts.get(groupPosition).setError(null);
        passportEditTexts.get(groupPosition).setError(null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return views.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return views.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

group.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textGroup"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
              android:textColor="@android:color/black"
              android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingLeft="20dp"
              android:paddingRight="20dp"
              android:focusable="false"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
              android:inputType="none"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/lastNameEditText"
              android:inputType="none"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/birthdayEditText"
              android:inputType="none"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/passportEditText"
              android:inputType="none"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

---

**Примечание:** в классе `Adapter` в функциях `onGroupCollapsed` и `onGroupExpanded` я добавил очистку полей, чтобы при следующем открытии они были пустыми и не провалидированными, этого можно и не делать, в зависимости от необходимого поведения.

Остальное должно быть понятно из названий функций. Если возникнут вопросы, отвечу на них в комментариях к ответу.

Comment: То же самое, валидация срабатываeт при клике на EditText...

Comment: В таком случае, информации предоставленной в вопросе недостаточно для ответа, так как пример из вопроса работает корректно. Можешь обновить вопрос и выложить полностью код активити? Так же не плохо было бы знать версию андроида под которую собираешь проект.

Comment: Обновил .......

Comment: Валидация срабатывает при первом клике на `EditText`? Или только при последующих? Появляется ли иконка ошибки (как в пункте 2 моего ответа) после того как фокус пропадает?

Comment: При первом клике норм и валидация срабатывает(Иконка с ошибкой) после потери фокуса. Фокус теряется потому что, я на другой EditText кликаю и там тоже сразу валидация срабатывает

Comment: Ок, сейчас попробую сделать проект с `ExpandableListView`, посмотрим, будет ли ломаться, отпишусь как закончу.

Comment: Спасибо заранее...

Comment: Добавил апдейт к ответу на вопрос (**UPD_1**), ложусь спать, как проснусь - продолжу и дополню ответ если найду решение.

Comment: @Omuradil, обновил ответ, решение нашлось, проверяй =)

Comment: Блиин!!! Спасибо вам огромное за помощь!!! Спасли, так сказать!

Comment: Не за что =) Я старался)

Comment: Тут так же решена проблема описанная в этом вопросе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509967/205673

Comment: Да, я не ожидал... спасибо еще раз огромное!!!

Comment: Если не сложно, поставь ответ как решение вопроса (галочка сбоку вопроса)

Comment: Ой извините, забыл)

Comment: Ivan Dembicki, можете подсказать, где и как могу получать данные с EditTextов?

Comment: Получить их можно у адаптера, сделав списки с `EditText` (`nameEditTexts` и т.п.) публичными (сейчас они приватные). Далее в активити можно будет брать их примерно так: `adapter.nameEditTexts.get(1).getText()` - берем текст из `EditText` из первой группы.

Comment: Спасибо, еще раз!

Comment: @Omuradil, Не за что =)

Answer (score 6):

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (v == editText && hasFocus == false) {
           ....
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: У меня даже так не работает, точнее срабатывает валидация при клике а не при потерии

Answer (score 3):

1. в `Manifest` прописать `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` для вашей активити
2. в `listview`  прописать `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"`
3. в `editText`  прописать `android:focusable="true", android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Пример на Kotlin:

```
EditText.onFocusChangeListener = OnFocusChangeListener { view: View, hasFocus: Boolean ->
    if (hasFocus == false)
        println("onFocusChangeListener: $hasFocus")
    else 
        println("onFocusChangeListener: $hasFocus")
}
```

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык