# Клонируется данные ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

У меня есть ExpandableListView и в нем несколько хидеров и в айтемах Поля ввода. Так вот ввожу данные в полях первого хидера и кликаю на второй хидер чтобы заролнить его поля, но там уже заполнены теми данными которые я вводил в первом, то есть тупо клонируется.

В чем проблема может быть, помогите!?

Вот сам **BookingActivity:**

```
public class BookingActivity extends BaseActivity {

    boolean isValid = true;

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    int adultPassCount = GlobalAppData.FlightSearchValues.adultPassenger;
    int childPassCount = GlobalAppData.FlightSearchValues.childPassenger;
    int babyPassCount = GlobalAppData.FlightSearchValues.infPassenger;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.booking_layout);

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        prepareListData();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        expListView.expandGroup(0);
    }
    public int GetPixelFromDips(float pixels) {
        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
    }

    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<>();

        List<String> adult = null;
        List<String> child = null;
        List<String> baby = null;

        for (int i = 1; i <= adultPassCount; i++){
            listDataHeader.add(getString(R.string.adultPassengers) + " " + i);
            adult = new ArrayList<>();
            adult.add("Adult " + i);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= childPassCount; i++){
            listDataHeader.add(getString(R.string.childPassengers) + " " + i);
            child = new ArrayList<>();
            child.add("Child " + i);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= babyPassCount; i++){
            listDataHeader.add(getString(R.string.infPassengers) + " " + i);
            baby = new ArrayList<>();
            baby.add("Baby " + i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < adultPassCount; i++){
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), adult);
        }

        if(childPassCount != 0){
            for (int i = adultPassCount; i < adultPassCount + childPassCount; i++){
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), child);
            }
        }
        if(babyPassCount != 0){
            if(childPassCount != 0){
                for (int i = adultPassCount + childPassCount; i < adultPassCount + childPassCount + babyPassCount; i++){
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), baby);
                }
            }
            for (int i = adultPassCount; i < adultPassCount + babyPassCount; i++){
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), baby);
            }
      }

}
```

**ExpandableListAdapter:**

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    String[] countries;
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    String[] data;
    public static EditText etBookingName;
    public static EditText etBookingLastname;
    public static EditText etBookingBirthday;
    public static AutoCompleteTextView etBookingNationality;
    public static Spinner spinner;
    public static EditText etBookingPassport;
    public static EditText etExpiryDate;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.booking_list_items, null);
            etBookingNationality = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingNationality);
            etBookingName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingName);
            etBookingLastname = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingLastname);
            etBookingBirthday = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingBirthday);
            etBookingPassport = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etBookingPassport);
            rgBookingGender = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rgBookingGender);
            etExpiryDate = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etDocumentExpiryDate);

                }
            });

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Кода много - не осилил, но проблема по любому в том, как вы устанавливаете данные в хэдэры. Попробуйте перед установкой данных полностью очистить поля ввода и проверьте какие и откуда данные берутся для подстановки.

Comment: Если честно, не очень понял(Что значит очистить поля, как проверить данные для подстановки)

Comment: Почитал немного код и не увидел там никаких хэдеров. Засим вопрос: что же у вас не работает?..

Comment: ListDataHeader - он идет как хидер каждого айтема, а listDataChild - как дочерний

Comment: Я всё ещё слабо понимаю что вы хотите своим кодом сказать бездушной машине) Попробуйте, что ли, в getChildView перед return convertView; всем вьюхам пустые значения проставить. Ну текст там и всё такое. А вообще... Вы что-то очень странное пытаетесь сделать. Статические поля-вьюхи в адаптере - это точно неправильно.

Comment: Неее, я всем едитам поставил значения правильно, просто тут удалил чтобы код не был огромным... Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не правильно, так как я это 3 дня делал поэтому хотелось бы узнать, поймите правильно

Comment: Статические поля содержат значения, одинаковые для всех экземпляров класса и, в вашем случае, одинаковые для всех элементов списка. Вам надо убрать из класса статические поля и сделать их внутренники переменными метода getChildView

Comment: не совсем понял(. Если не трудно можете одну строку показать как пример.

Comment: `EditText etBookingName;` и остальные должны быть без `public static` и идти сразу перед `if (convertView == null)`